# Stretch space characters horizontally

Tags: fonts, spacing, xetex, formatting

I'm using XeTeX to mimic another document, but I only have a similar font which I stretch using the `extend` and `letterspace` options.

My main problem is though, that my font's spaces (U+0020) are only about half as wide as the original font's. I don't want to use U+2000 to U+200A, because I want to be able to change the exact width without re-editing everything. I defined

```
\newcommand{\K}{\hspace{1.2ex}}
```

But that's very verbose to use: `Hello\K{}World`

What I'd really like is an option that allows me to define a factor to stretch spaces by (it may disable TeX's automatic stretching, I don't use justified text or even automatic line breaks anyway), but I only found those for vertical spaces…

---

This works with `pdflatex` but not with my versions (3.1415926-2.2-0.9995.2 TeX Live 2009/Debian and 0.9997.4 TeX Live 2010) of `xelatex`. So a solution not using microtype would be nice…

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[tracking=true]{microtype}

\DeclareMicrotypeSet*[tracking]{my}{font = */*/*/*/*}
\SetTracking[spacing={1000,,}]{font = */*/*/*/*}{1}

\begin{document}
 \lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't relly understand how the "texlive" tag is relevant here. The question would be the same with MikTeX, for example.

Comment: I thought it was a problem with my XeTeX version, since updating to TeX Live 2010 solved another `fontspec`-related problem for me, but I remove the tag now

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the case of pdflatex you can change `\spaceskip` (affects all fonts) or `\fontdimen2` (affects only one font).  In the case of xelatex: look up in the documentation of fontspec - section "interword space" - the option `WordSpace`.

Comment: Great, thanks. Fontspec also supports the other options I used with plain `\font`: `FakeBold`=`embolden`, `FakeStretch`=`extend`, `LetterSpace`=`letterspace` (but with different units, for some reason)

Answer (score 1):

package microtype knows the `\textls` comamnd

Comment: I seem to have an issue with `\textls` and TikZ: `! Undefined control sequence.
\tikz@invoke@collected@onpath ...mmand \tikz@temp[HERE]
\pgf@stop \tikz@node@is@a@...` but my line spacing has a problem, too, so I think that's unrelated. Thanks!

Comment: give a complete example, not only fragments

Comment: Solved that problem now, but I now have found out that spacing doesn't seem to work with XeTeX: (see question)
When compiled using `pdflatex` spaces are double wide, but there's no effect using `xelatex`. I see that they are just now implementing it, back to LaTeX then…